# Prevent table from being updated while updating und deleting rows

Tags: mysql

I'm bulding a matchmaking system for a little game. My table which saves all players searching for opponents looks like this:

```
lobby
----------
userID
points
range
opponentID
```

Every 5 seconds the script tries to find an opponent within a certain range of points.

```sql
UPDATE lobby SET
    opponentID = {myUserID}
WHERE points >= {myPoints} - {myRange} AND points <= {myPoints} + {myRange}
    AND opponentID = 0 AND userID != {myUserID}
ORDER BY ABS(points - {myPoints}) ASC
LIMIT 1
```

If there are affected rows I remove the current player from the lobby and get the opponents ID:

```sql
DELETE FROM lobby
WHERE userID = {myUserID}

SELECT userID FROM lobby
WHERE opponentID = {myUserID}
```

Now my fear is that someone assigns the current user between the UPDATE and DELETE. How can I prevent this? Can I combine the UPDATE and DELETE?

Comment: You will have to start a transaction and put both statements within that transaction.

Comment: You are using presence of a row in lobby to indicate state about rows in another table. Instead, delete the lobby table entirely and have an "available" column in your player table. Then you will find most of your synchronization problems go away. And it's the right design anyway.

Comment: @Bohemian Sounds good, but then I have the same problem between updating the opponentID and available from Player1 and setting available to 0 from Player2